# gdb gives warning "Could not open OSO archive file"

Tags: debugging, gdb

I just installed gdb using home-brew. I made a certificate and codesigned it. When I "run" the program in gdb (in terminal) it gives the warnings

```
warning: `/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.40.1~1/Objects/coretls.build/coretls.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/system_coretls_vers.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.40.1~1/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_ciphersuites.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.40.1~1/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_handshake.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.40.1~1/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_record.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.40.1~1/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_stream_parser.a"
```

But gdb still works, i.e. I can still debug the program. What do these warnings mean and how do I fix them?

Comment: Do you know what part of your program trigger these warnings? Maybe you could talk a little about your code.

Comment: I don't think it's the program's fault, since I ran gdb on three different programs and they all give the same warnings.

Comment: Have you tried to install what's not finding?

Comment: What is what's not finding?

Comment: libcoretls, I figured. Normally I install what is missing. In my Linux, I never had that problem with gdb so I can't help you directly. You could try looking for it in the package manager. Nevertheless, you can still benefit yourself from gdb until no one answers you.

Comment: There's this libcore available at my package manager. I googled it and sounds like a library gdb can use. I hope you can find a way throught it.